# Publish project to BitBucket from VS2013

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am new in bitbucket. so first i create my login there and create two repositories. one is public and one is private. when i am trying to publish my existing project from VS2013 to bitbucket then i am getting error as following

> You cannot publish local branch master to the remote repository origin
>   because a branch with the same name already exists there. You might
>   want to rename your local branch and try again.

screen shot
[image]

i follow this article http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-bitbucket-with-visual-studio-2015/

some one please guide me why i am getting the above error when i am trying to add my existing local project to **bitbucket git**?

Thanks